# Couldn't find that process types (web)

Tags: django, heroku, web-deployment

I was trying to host my django app on heroku when I saw the error stating web processes are not working
so when searched for I saw that I have to use command:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

after that I got error:

```
(djangoProject1) C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\djangoProject1>heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... 
     Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

Comment: Try `heroku apps:info -a <app_name>` to see the info about the app